# amcharts V4 Redirect to URL on selection in pie chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Like this example, how do you add support for redirecting on a url when someone clicks on a slice.

Like on [this](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/GPqQrM) example.

I have tried doing what the documentation requires:

```js
 if (cbSeriesClicked !== undefined) {
        pieSeries.events.on("hit", cbSeriesClicked, this);

    }
```

The event fires, but im unable able to figure out where in the chart object the currently selected slice is, or if amcharts 4 supports https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/linking-chart-columns-custom-urls/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AmCharts 4 equivalent is to use [`propertyFields`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Property_fields) on the series/series sub item template, depending on the chart type and set the [`url`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/slice/#url_property) property to match up with the property in your data containing the URL. You can also set [`urlTarget`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/slice/#urlTarget_property) to control whether it opens in a new tab or not. For pie charts, you have to set it on the sub item template like so:

```
//assumes your data contains a property called "url":
var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
// ...
pieSeries.slices.template.propertyFields.url = "url";
pieSeries.slices.template.urlTarget = "_blank";
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/0951428a66b1e2cc6dccddf6d9690da9?editors=1010)